# How to vectorize dict_keys to list converting?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have an 2D-array of dict_keys array and want to convert it to 3D-array.

```
Y =  array([[Counter({'Q': 1, 'S': 1}),
        Counter({'Z': 2, 'P': 2, 'L': 1})],
       [Counter({'I': 2}),
        Counter({'R': 2, 'Q': 1})]], dtype=object)
```

I have vectorKeys, which give me

```
vectorKeys(Y) =  array([[dict_keys(['Q','S']),
        dict_keys(['Z','P', 'L']],
       [dict_keys(['I']),
        dict_keys(['R','Q'])]], dtype=object)
```

and i want to get

```
Y =  array([[['Q','S'],
        ['Z','P', 'L']],
       [['I'],
        ['R','Q']]], dtype=object)
```

I tried to get it with

```
vectorList = np.vectorize(list)
vectorNPArray = np.vectorize(np.array)
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: you can't do that, the inner arrays are mismatched in number of columns. Use regular lists

Comment: `dtype=object` means no vectorization. Internally, Numpy cannot vectorize things working on objects so it does a loop like you could do. You may not pay the interpreter overhead though similar to a Cython script. Most of the overhead comes from objects. If you want a fast code, you need not to use objects but native types instead. `np.vectorize` does not (really) vectorize the function (based on the definition provided by Numpy). This is just a convenient wrapper.